# C Return Struct Pointer after Function Call Value Gets Lost

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to figure out why my struct value is lost after the function return.

```
struct A {
   int val1;
   int val2;
}

main() {
   struct A *a;
   a->val1 = 1;
   a->val2 = 2;
   calc((void*)a);
   // calc returns and a's values are 1 and 2 respectively
}

void calc(void* v) {
     struct A *a = (struct A*) v;
     ...
     a->val1 = 2;
     a->val2 = 3;
}
```

Comment: In `main`: `struct A *a; a->val1 = 1;` Where do you think `a` is pointing to? Pointers must not be dereferenced unless they are pointing to valid memory.

Comment: `a` should be an address in the stack (please correct me if I'm wrong). I tried to malloc space for `a` but still got the same result.

Comment: Why have you defined `main()` to return a `struct A`?  You are missing a key semicolon!

Comment: @Celeste Why should `a` be an address on the stack? Where do you assign `a` a value that's an address on the stack? Sure, `a` itself is a location on the stack, but `a` itself is a pointer. You need an actual `A`, not just a pointer to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to deal with pointers, you have to introduce dynamic memory allocation. Creating a pointer means you are telling compiler that 'I am going to store address of variable in it'. So in this case, either you create an object assign address to it or allocate memory to it dynamically.

Case 1:

```
main() {
   struct A *a;
   struct A obj;//assign address of other object manually
   a = &obj;
   a->val1 = 1;
   a->val2 = 2;
   calc((void*)a);
   // calc returns and a's values are 1 and 2 respectively
}
```

Case 2:

```
main() {
   struct A *a;
   a = (A *) malloc(sizeof(A));//dynamic memory allocation
   a->val1 = 1;
   a->val2 = 2;
   calc((void*)a);
   // calc returns and a's values are 1 and 2 respectively
}
```

Comment: I got myself confused with addresses and pointers. It's working now :)